# Date Input in Safari showing current date as place holder only

Tags: html, safari

I have an issue where `input` field of type `date` is displaying the current date even though the field has no value. I have tried:

`... placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy">`

but the problem still persists. Is there any other way of setting this place holder without changing the type of the input field?